# Swapping images in an IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, model-view-controller, iboutletcollection

I am having trouble correctly swapping two UIImageViews stored in an IBOutletCollection.  Conceptually, I must be doing something wrong.

Let's say I have an NSMutableArray of indexed data, and an NSMutableArray of indexed UIImageViews, where I would like the two indexed arrays to correspond, i.e. the nth-indexed element of the UIImageView array should reflect the nth data element in the image array.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(MyImageView) NSMutableArray* myImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* myData;
```

At the outset, I sort my IBOutletCollection by x-coordinate so that the appearance on the screen is left-to-right, i.e. the element of index 0 should appear all the way to the left, ..., all the way to the right of the screen.

```
NSComparisonResult imageSort(id label1, id label2, void* context)
{
    if ([label1 frame].origin.x < [label2 frame].origin.x)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if ([label1 frame].origin.x > [label2 frame].origin.x)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else { // Determine using y-coordinate
        if ([label1 frame].origin.y < [label2 frame].origin.y)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if ([label1 frame].origin.y > [label2 frame].origin.y)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else
            return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I want to swap two members of the data array, I make sure to swap their images as well, so that each UIImageView will always reflect the data in that slot.  Let's say the two elements I want to swap have indices frontIndex and backIndex:

```
// Switch state data in arrays
Data* sendToBack = myData[frontIndex];
Data* bringToFront = myData[backIndex];

myData[frontIndex] = bringToFront;
myData[backIndex] = sendToBack;

MyImageView* sendToBackImg = myImages[frontIndex];
MyImageView* bringToFrontImg = myImages[backIndex];

myImages[frontIndex] = bringToFrontImg;
myImages[backIndex] = sendToBackImg;
```

The problem happens when I try to animate or update the image array.  It appears that when I call animate or update on the updated array element at index 0 and 9, the views that actually update aren't the ones located leftmost and 9th from the left: they're updating in their new locations:

```
[myImages[frontIndex] animateInWayX]; --> this updates the on-screen view at backIndex
[myImages[backIndex] animateInWayY];  --> this updates the on-screen view at frontIndex
```

I checked the arrays in the debugger, and the swap did happen -- in other words, the frontIndex element inside the myImages array does show the proper data reflecting the model at myData[frontIndex], so the view array is properly swapped, it's just displaying at a new location on the screen (the location of backIndex, as if it didn't move).

How do I fix this?

Comment: are you updating the view? [self.view setNeedsDisplay] and/or [self.view layoutIfNeeded]

Comment: that happens inside animateInWayX, so it has nothing to do with the display, as when the animation happens, it has to use the freshest data

Comment: I feel like the root of the problem is that the X & Y coordinates of the individual MyImageViews are set in stone from the moment i declare them, so even if I change their slot in the IBOutletArray, the imageViews themselves never move. I need to find some way to refresh data inside an imageView instead of just redirecting pointers... ?

Comment: another thing I just thought about ... are you using auto layout constraints? If you are, you'll need to update the constraint (and [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]) And regarding the UIImageViews, NSLog the UIImage property to make sure their address in fact change as well.

Comment: I think you are swapping pointers instead of swapping the images themselves. Since the positions of the imageviews do not get swapped when you swap the pointers,  you are not getting the desired result. NSLog the origin of the imageviews' frames to check this out.

Comment: I think you're right. So the solution is either to (a.) move the physical frame itself (i.e. swap & reassign the ImageView frame origins), or (b.) have the ImageView "refresh" or reload data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as commenter above pointed out, you are swapping pointers only. Best solution is to copy contents being pointed-to.

```
// Switch state data in arrays
Data* temp = [[DataObject alloc] init];

[self copyDataFrom:bringToFront into:temp];
[self copyDataFrom:sendToBack into:myData[frontIndex]];
[self copyDataFrom:temp into:myData[backIndex]];

MyImageView* frontImg = myImages[frontIndex];
MyImageView* backImg = myImages[backIndex];

[frontImg updateUsingData:myData[frontIndex]];
[backImg updateUsingData:myData[backIndex]];
```